# Style function called twice for each feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I wonder why my style function is called twice for each feature added to the layer. This is the code I have:

```
var features = new ol.Collection(),
layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),
    style: function(feature, resolution){
        console.log("called it"); // <-- called twice for each feature
        return getStyle(feature);  
    }
});
map.addLayer(layer);
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: features,
    type: (geomType)
});         
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

I cannot figure out why style function is called twice, every time when I add a feature to the map. It becomes a problem and looks like a terrible overhead when the number of features increases.

**EDIT**

Well, I got it. In fact I provided irreproducible code. In reality, I `set` one feature attribute inside style function. And it seems like when you use `feature.set(...)`, then style function is called again. So, the problem has been solved.

Comment: Since you solved the problem on your own, and there are no answers yet. Please consider locking or deleting this question.

Comment: I provided an answer. The problem was that setting any property on a feature triggers style function.

Comment: Then post your answer as an actual answer, and accept your own answer.